# Creating table with interior horizontal lines not reaching the margins

Tags: tables

I want to create a table as on the picture below. But I do not know how to get those beautiful looking horizontal lines.

I also want to have a table with enough space from the lines to the text, this is done quite good in the template below.

[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: For this question, there are LOTS of examples of questions about tables on TeX.SX. Try searching and you will quickly be able to answer your own question!

Comment: @Andrew IMHO, the full minimal working example can start by `\vbox{...` and ends by `\bye`. We need not to use `\documentclass`.

Comment: @wipet Sorry, you're right. I will try to reform! :)

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of the `\hhline` macro (provided by the `hhline` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X l |}
\hline
 & V & R & \\
 \hhline{|~==~|}   % double line
 & B & b & \\
 \hhline{|~--~|}   % single line
 & C & c & \\
 \hhline{|~--~|}
 & & & \\
 \hhline{|~--~|}
 & & & \\
 \hhline{|~--~|}
 & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, this is exactly what I am looking for. Could you please explain the command `>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X`?

Comment: @user144921 - That command is explained in the user guide of the `tabularx` package. By default, if one sets up two `X` columns, they will be equally wide. If, in contrast,you want to make the first `X` column three times as wide as the second -- something that seems to be desirable, judging by the screenshot you posted -- one can modify the relative widths; the main constraint is that the sum of the relative widths must be equal to the number of `X` columns. In the present case, `1.5+0.5= 2`.

Answer (score 3):

There should be other ways of doing this. You can adjust the dimensions to suit your purpose.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|lp{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}r|}
  \hline
  &V&R&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\[-2.0ex]\cline{2-3}
  &B&b&\\\cline{2-3}
  &C&c&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\\cline{2-3}
  &&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the widths of columns are fixed, you need not to use `\halign` (i.e. any of environments like `tabular`, `tabularx` etc.). Only `\hbox to dimen` is sufficient:

```
\vbox{\hrule\hbox to\hsize{\vrule\hfil\vbox{\advance\hsize by-2em \kern2pt
   \def\ph#1&#2\\{\pd{#1}{#2}\hrule}
   \def\p#1&#2\\{\kern1pt\hrule \pd{#1}{#2}}
   \def\pd#1#2{\hbox{\lower7pt\vbox to20pt{}\pdi{.7}{#1}\pdi{.3}{\tt#2}}}
   \def\pdi#1#2{\hbox to#1\hsize{\ \ignorespaces#2\unskip\hfil}}

\ph A & B \\
\p  C & D \\
\p  E & F \\
\p  F & G \\

}\hfil\vrule}\hrule}

\bye
```

Comment: Your result looks really nice, but is it possible to change the width of the box? Currently it reaches from left margin to right margin. I would like to decrease the width.

Comment: @user144921 Declare `\newdimen\tabwidth \tabwidth=7cm` and replace all occurrences of `\hsize` by `\tabwidth` in the code.